# How to extract the word which is longer than 5 chars. in a word list?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to write a Python function that takes in a list of strings and returns a new list containing only the strings that are longer than 5 characters.

I have written the following code:

```
def filter_long_words(words):
    long_words = []
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > 5:
            long_words.append(word)
    return long_words
```

However, when I run the function with the input ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date'], I get the output ['banana', 'cherry'] instead of the expected output ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']. Can anyone help me figure out why my function is not working as expected?

Comment: Why do you expect that `'apple'` should be included?

Comment: I think the problem is not with the program, but with the expectations.

Comment: Perhaps you really wanted to use `>=` but typed `>` instead?

Comment: As ^^^ prev. comments you prob. miss the greater_than_equal sign?  You could also do this way - ```return [w for w in words if len(w) >= 5]```

Comment: The function works exactly as you *instruct* it to do.  ;-)

Comment: Your code is correct according to your specification - i.e., "...strings that are **longer** than 5 characters"

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that "apple" have 5 words on the if statement compares the length of the string that has more than 5 words. That means the condition is True if the number of words is greater or equal to 6 words.
To make you condition works correctly use:

```py
if len(word) >= 5:
```

or

```py
if len(word) > 4:
```

A better code could be:

```py
long_words = [word for word in words if len(word) >= 5]
```

or

```py
long_words = list(filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 5, words))
```